# SE PIERDE POSICION AL HACER POSTBACK DE BOOTSTRAP DATEPICKER CON UPDATEPANEL

Tags: bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-3

Saludos a todos:

Tengo un inconveniente con el despliegue de un datepicker que se encuentra dentro de un UpdatePanel. Al iniciar la pagina esta carga bien el calendario (días en español y meses igual) pero al momento de generar un postback los calendarios pierden este formato y ademas se posicionan en la parte superior del textbox que esta asignado a este. dejo el siguiente código html:

```html
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Reporte.aspx.vb" Inherits="Reporte" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="Toolkit" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Control/ctrMenu.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="ctrMenu" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Control/ctrMensaje.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="ctrMensaje" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Control/ctrFooter.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="ctrFooter" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Valida.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/sweetalert2.js"></script>
    <link href="Styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Styles/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Styles/sweetalert2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Styles/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Styles/Loading.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            padding-top: 30px;
        }
        .row
        {
            padding-bottom: 3px;
        }
    </style> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

            function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                $('#txtFechaInicio').datepicker();
                $('#txtFechaInicio').removeClass('form-control input-sm datepicker');
                $('#txtFechaInicio').addClass('form-control input-sm datepicker');
            }
        });
    </script>   

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/lte-ie7.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <Toolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="scriptManager" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" />
    <uc1:ctrMenu runat="server" ID="ctrMenu" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="udpPrincipal">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="container" class="container">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li>
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">Home</asp:HyperLink></li>
                    <li class="active">Reportes </li>
                </ol>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                        <div id="filter-panel" class="filter-panel">
                            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    Filtros de Búsqueda</div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Tipo Accion">
                                            Modulo</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlModulo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control input-sm"
                                                rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Modulo" Width="240px">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </div>
                                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Tipo Accion">
                                            Sucursal</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOficina" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-sm"
                                                rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Sucursal" Width="240px">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Tipo Accion">
                                            Tipo de Fecha</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblTipoFecha" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Curse" Value="1" style="margin-right:50px;"></asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Text="Gesti&oacute;n" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group form-inline ">
                                            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Fecha Inicio">
                                                Fecha Registro Desde</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFechaInicio" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-sm datepicker"
                                                        onkeypress="return permite(event, 'fecha')" Width="205px"></asp:TextBox><span class="input-group-addon input-sm"><i
                                                            class="fa fa-lg fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Fecha Fin">
                                                Hasta</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFechaFin" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-sm datepicker"
                                                        onkeypress="return permite(event, 'fecha')" Width="205px"></asp:TextBox><span class="input-group-addon input-sm"><i
                                                            class="fa fa-lg fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFechas" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <asp:Table ID="Table1" Style="float: none; margin: 0 auto;" runat="server">
                                            <asp:TableRow>
                                                <asp:TableCell>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btoBuscar" OnClick="btoBuscar_Click" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;  Buscar</asp:LinkButton>
                                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btoLimpiar" OnClick="btoLimpiar_Click" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-sm"
                                                        ><i class="fa fa-eraser fa-lg"></i> Limpiar</asp:LinkButton>
                                                </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
                                        </asp:Table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnExportar" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right " Visible="false"
                            OnClick="btoExportar_Click"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o fa-lg"></i>  Exportar a Excel </asp:LinkButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updPanel">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <uc1:ctrMensaje runat="server" ID="ctrMensaje" Visible="false" />
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="Grilla" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover"
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"  
                                    PageSize="5">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Modulo" DataField="MODULO" /> 
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Monto Promedio Cursado" DataField="MONTO_PROMEDIO" />
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Suma Monto Cursado" DataField="SUMA_MONTO" Visible="false" />
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="N° Curses" DataField="CANTIDAD_CURSADAS" />
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="N° Gestiones" DataField="CANTIDAD_GESTIONES" /> 
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="% Gestion" DataField="PORCENTAJE_GESTION" /> 
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GrillaOficina" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover"
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"   OnRowDataBound="grdRegistros_RowDataBound"
                                    PageSize="5">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Modulo" DataField="MODULO" />
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Oficina" DataField="OFICINA" />
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Monto Promedio Cursado" DataField="MONTO_PROMEDIO" />
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Suma Monto Cursado" DataField="SUMA_MONTO"  Visible="false" />
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="N° Curses" DataField="CANTIDAD_CURSADAS" />
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="N° Gestiones" DataField="CANTIDAD_GESTIONES" /> 
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="% Gestion" DataField="PORCENTAJE_GESTION" /> 
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DisplayAfter="0" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="udpPrincipal">
                    <ProgressTemplate>
                        <div class="overlay" />
                        <div class="overlayContent">
                            <h2>Buscando Resultados...</h2>
                            <img src="Images/Consultando.gif" alt="buscando" border="1" height="170px" width="170px" />
                        </div>
                    </ProgressTemplate>
                </asp:UpdateProgress>

            <uc1:ctrFooter runat="server" ID="ctrFooter" />
        </div>
        </ContentTemplate> 
    </asp:UpdatePanel> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Se entiende que debo registrar nuevamente el HTML de los datepicker cuando este efectua el postback, lo que no logro aun es mantener la misma posicion inicial del datepicker y además de su formato ya que despues del postback me muestra el calendario en ingles.
Adjunto imagen donde indica la posición inicial y después en la posición que queda después del postback:

Posición Inicial: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posición después del Postback:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida de todas maneras y quedo atento a su ayuda mientras sigo en búsqueda de datos que me ayuden a resolver este problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado el problema, cuando se efectua el postback el datepicker no carga los formatos que carga en un inicio, por ende se deben agregar al momento de hacer nuevamente la carga del datepicker como se muetsra a continuación.

```html
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                $('#txtFechaInicio').datepicker({ language: 'es', todayBtn: 'true', autoclose: 'true', weekStart: 1, todayHighlight: true });
                $('#txtFechaFin').datepicker({ language: 'es', todayBtn: 'true', autoclose: 'true', weekStart: 1, todayHighlight: true });
            }
```

De esta manera el calendario queda en su misma posición y con las mismas características que cuando se inicio.

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar este problema debemos seguir los siguientes pasos.

Seleccionamos el ScriptManager y accedemos a la ventana de propiedades

Cambiamos a True los siguientes valores.

```
EnableScriptGlobalization
EnableScriptLocalization
```

Por ultimo accedemos a la seccion de código de la página y en la primera linea agregamos los siguientes parámetros

```
Culture="Auto"

UICulture="Auto"
```

Ejemplo:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="pruebaCalendario.aspx.vb" Inherits="pruebaCalendario" Culture="Auto" UICulture="Auto"%>
```

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responder, he agregado ambas lineas que me faltaban según lo que tu me has indicado pero el problema persiste. Una vez que agregue lo que faltaba borre la cache del navegador (Chrome) y volví a ejecutar el proyecto sin cambio alguno